# Unable to reset my terminal when screen is on

Tags: shell

I have the following in my .zshrc

```
if [[ $STY = '' ]] then screen -xR; fi
```

I made a few changes to my .zshrc.

I run unsuccessfully to see changes

```
reset
```

I also restarted my shell unsuccessfully to see the changes.
This suggests me that the screen needs to be restarted somehow.

**How can you restart screen** such that I see the changes in my .zshrc?

Comment: Given the amount of trouble you're having with zsh, you might want to consider switching to bash - you'll almost certainly get better support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*source ~/.zshrc*

Also maybe *killall screen*, then just start screen again?

Comment: Thank you! @ Another way is to just logout by Ctrl-D.